# Get Row Number with Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

Super noob question here. I have an array of row indexes that I would like to use to change the color of my Handsontable rows. I figure HOT would provide a method to retrieve the `tr` element of a table with something like `hot.getRow(5)`, but it doesn't seem to exist.

So in a nutshell I'm trying to do this

```
var rowIds = []
$.each(rowIds , function (i, element) {
    var row = hot.getRow(i);
    $(row).closest('tr').css('color','green');
});
```

I've found I can use `getCell()` method which accepts a row and column # along with a boolean, but using this would require extra code for something that should be as simple as passing a single  argument. Is there a method I'm overlooking or is this the only way?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing with how HOT works: it is a JS object which renders a stateless DOM table. This means you should never EVER try to manually modify the HTML of your table. Even if you did want to do that, as soon as you make a change to those green cells, they would get re-rendered, not green.

Instead, you want to use the readily accessible 'custom renderers' that are associated with each column or cell, depending on how you define them. These are applied just like the `data` attribute in the `columns` or `cells` definition. They are functions and here's an example:

```
function greenCellRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.color = 'green';
}
```

You should read up on the full documentation to understand the full power of the renderer but it's pretty clear from the arguments it takes what you can do. One thing you would be able to do is apply the green color you're hoping for. Of course to selectively do this you would either apply the renderer to specific cells, or put a conditional inside this general renderer using the `row` and `col` arguments to your advantage.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Zeke, I am new to HOT and with all new frameworks I have a thousand questions. Can these custom renderers be declared after a table is already loaded? i.e., say on the success or failure of an `$.ajax()` call that has persisted data from a modified table instance?

Comment: yup, there's a powerful method called `updateSettings` which lets you update any of the original settings. You could update the `columns` or `cells` with new renderers. I suggest, however, keeping a map of all "blacklisted" cells and having the ajax call update this. Then in your renderer, check if the current `[row,col]` is in this map and if so, apply some logic. This way you don't have to be updating renderers all the time. But updating renderers is also a good way to go.